# Get checked checkboxes trigger event on sibling elements

Tags: javascript

I have these buttons and want to click the selected ones at one time

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label><button onclick="alert('a')">button1</button></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label><button onclick="alert('b')">button2</button></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label><button onclick="alert('c')">button3</button></label>
</div>
<button>go</button>
```

I tried some jquery stuff but not made it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
In JS we are selected button with checkbox status checked and then triggering click event.

```js
function go() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label > button').forEach(function(element){
    element.click();
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="checkbox" >
   <label ><button onclick="alert('a')">button1</button></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="checkbox" >
   <label ><button onclick="alert('b')">button2</button></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="checkbox" >
   <label ><button onclick="alert('c')">button3</button></label>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="go()">go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just giving you *some code*:

- You're not assigning any click to your GO button (Why?)
- Add an ID to your *GO* button to help you query it in JS
- Assign a `class` to your checkboxes as well. Like: `class="chk"`
- Don't use unsafe inline `on*` handlers. JS should be in one place only, and that's its respective tag or file. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead
- Makes no sense to use `<button>` inside `<label>` since it will steal the focus.
- Your checkboxes are missing the `value` attribute. Use that attribute to store the desired value.
- You're missing `for` attributes. Either add `id` to your INPUTs and `for` to your labels, or just wrap everything inside the LABEL
- You're missing `type="button"` on your buttons
- Avoid the use of `prompt`, `alert`. Replace those with a proper UI. For testing purpose use `console`

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// Task:

const doSomething = (EL_chk) => {
  // Do something...
  console.log(EL_chk.value);
};

// Add change events to each checkbox
ELS(".chk").forEach((EL_chk) => {
   EL_chk.addEventListener("input", () => doSomething(EL_chk));
});

// On button GO click, target the checked ones
EL("#go").addEventListener("click", () => {
  ELS(".chk:checked").forEach(doSomething);
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="a">
    <!-- DON'T USE <button> INSIDE A LABEL -->
    <span class="btn">button A</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="b">
    <span class="btn" data-click="a">button B</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="c">
    <span class="btn">button C</span>
  </label>
</div>

<button id="go" class="btn" type="button">GO</button>
```